# Django image upload test error: "The attribute has no file associated with it"

Tags: python, django

I have a user profile app that allows a user to upload an avatar. I'm trying to test the image upload but am getting an error. Here are my relevant files:

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/", blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def userprofile(request):
    # some code omitted for brevity
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(userprofile.get_absolute_url())
```

tests.py

```
class UserProfileTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='testuser',
            email='test@test.test',
            password='testpassword',
        )
        self.user.userprofile.first_name = 'John'
        self.user.userprofile.last_name = 'Doe'

    def test_image_upload(self):
        self.client.login(username='testuser', password='testpassword')
        with open('media/tests/up.png', 'rb') as image:
            self.client.post('/profile/', {'avatar': image})
        print(self.user.userprofile.avatar.url)
```

Error:

```
File "userprofile/tests.py", line 110, in test_image_upload
  print(self.user.userprofile.avatar.url)
ValueError: The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

In the tests, I've printed the `response.content` and can see the avatar's URL in the template. The `'media/tests/up.png'` file is on the server and is being uploaded successfully. My goal here is to delete the file at the end of the test because it uploads every time I run the tests. I was going to delete the file by getting its file path (Django appends random alpha-numeric characters to the end of the file name when there are duplicates), but I can't get its file path right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need a django file object for the test. You can make a python file and then have a django ImageFile :

```
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

with open('media/tests/up.png', 'rb') as image:
    test_file = ImageFile(image)
```

And then use test_file for the test.

Comment: Hey thanks for checking this out. I'm actually still getting the same error. I replaced "image" with "test_file" in the response.client.post and I still see it successfully uploading when I print response.content but it's still telling me: "ValueError: The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it."

Comment: try to add the relative path : ```ImageFile(image, name='media/tests/up.png')```

Comment: Same error here. Your use of ImageFile got me researching it, which led me to SimpleUploadedFile. I tried a similar approach with SimpleUploadedFile and got the same error, so it makes me think that this part of the app isn't the problem. I'm going to dig elsewhere now that I have this part sorted out. Thanks again for all your help and I'll be sure to post an answer when I've figured it out.